# I can't create a mark-down link when editing an existing answer

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, markdown, character-limit

Since more than 6 characters need to change when editing an answer, I can't convert a textual link to a real link:

Original Text

> More info: I've been looking at cocoahttpserver (http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) > but it would be nice to have an embeddable server which supported output templates like rails, php, django, etc.

After the edit (changing less than 6 characters)

> More info: I've been looking at [cocoahttpserver](http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/) > but it would be nice to have an embeddable server which supported output templates like rails, php, django, etc.

I understand that very short edits might not generally have much value, but having links which aren't clickable are quite annoying, even if the edit only changes 4 characters.

Comment: Are you sure that the missing link is the only thing wrong with the post?

Comment: Assuming that the post is very short only containing the link I guess it's perfectly possible that the link is the only edit. Of course I could change some words and use synonyms in order to save my edit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the times, there's also something else to fix: minor grammar mistake, missing punctuation etc, so just fix some extra stuff and all is good.

If there's nothing else to fix or you're short in time, you can just leave comment on the post letting its author to edit it when he/she will see the comment.

Other than that can't see much to do.. maybe feature request asking that changing a link will "cancel" the 6 character filter.

Comment: or include the link markup as part of the character count in which case every changes to a from textual to actual link would be above the limit ("http://".length > 6)

Comment: @Runefs possibly.. if this will come as feature request. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you would have changed the text to be as the following one, you would have edited more than six characters.

```
More info: I've been looking at [CocoaHTTPServer][1], but it would be nice to have an embeddable server which supported output templates like Ruby on Rails, PHP, Django, etc.


  [1]: http://code.google.com/p/cocoahttpserver/
```

In this way, you would have fixed the spelling of some words (which should have been written using a different letter case), and changed "Rails" in "Ruby on Rails" (which is exact name). You would have fixed more in  the post, and been able to propose it.