# Drop the current 6 character minimum for broken hyperlink edits

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Legitimate edits of less than 6 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149771/legitimate-edits-of-less-than-6-characters)

There should be a way to do small edits in special cases. Could not edit a users answer to correct a bad hyperlink because the proposed edit did not meet the 6 character change minimum.

See the hyperlink in user Erick Fernandes answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7313944/natural-language-processing-in-javascript). *The hyperlink contains an unintentional period (.) character at the end of it which breaks the link.*

Comment: The reason for the minimum for <2K users is that there is a cost associated with suggested edits, specifically the reviewers' time.  There is no such minimum on users with >2K rep since those edits don't need reviewed.  If less than 6 char edits were allowed, there for be far too many useless edits than justifiable small edits like this.

Comment: Wow, that user is a real minefield of one-line-can-you-search-something-for-me-questions...

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby do you mean it's time, to quote Pekka, for the ["Friday Afternoon Off-Topic Question Massacre"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155169/why-was-my-answer-on-the-java-reporting-tools-question-deleted#comment445707_155169) - 10k only, i.e. not me :-(. Shouldn't be done with a single user but someone should pick a topic soon, NLP?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: Well, yes, that would make me happy.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is:

> I've developed a small library to be used directly on browser. You can
>   download it from [here][1]
>
> [1]:
>   http://www.erickfernandes.com/post/2012/04/17/natjs-Javascript-Library-for-NLP.aspx.

You can re-write this as:

> I've developed a small library to be used directly on a browser. You can
>   download it from [here](http://www.erickfernandes.com/post/2012/04/17/natjs-Javascript-> Library-for-NLP.aspx).

Changes made (excluding whitespace):

1. *"directly on browser"* to *"directly on a browser"* - 1 character
2. Remove `[1]:` - 4 characters
3. Add 2 parenthesis - 2 characters
4. I think adding a correct full-stop after *"here"* will count as an edit as well.

I've changed 7-8 characters in total whilst making the answer more grammatically correct.

There's no need to change the limit.

I've also edited the actual answer, not that it's a very good...

Comment: But some people don't have so much time to spend fiddling around on stackexchange, and might just spot a broken link and want to fix it. I genuinely believe fixing dead links should be as easy as clicking edit and sticking the new link in